# Sqlite database datetime not returning desired results

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I don't understand why my print is giving me results prior to Jan 01 2004, any help is appreciated.

```
import sqlite3
connection=sqlite3.connect("reviewx2.db")
cursor=connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT date FROM review WHERE date >='01-jan-2004'")

for i in range(10):
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    print(result)
```

prints:
('October 11, 2005',)
('January 7, 2004',)
('December 30, 2003',)
('March 18, 2004',)
('August 28, 2005',)
('September 25, 2005',)
('April 16, 2004',)
('April 3, 2004',)
('November 24, 2003',)
('February 2, 2004',)

Comment: Which type is `date` column?

Comment: I set it as DATE

Comment: Start by reading https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype

Comment: Then realize you're comparing strings. All those strings are greater than a string starting with the character `0`.